Blazor Server app, JavaScript files stop working when trying to load blazor.server.js
I have a problem that I am facing while working with Blazor Server in .NET 8. My JavaScript scripts stop working correctly when I try to load the script
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

in the _Layout.cshtml file.
When I include this script, my own JavaScript scripts stop working (they actually work for a fraction of a second, then the screen flickers and the scripts stop working). However, when I remove the references to .js files in _Layout.cshtml and place them directly in files like page1.razor, everything works fine.
File _Layout.cshtml:
<base href="~/" />

<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="js/test/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test/swiper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test/gallery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test/Pager.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test/picture.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>


I would like all my references to JavaScript files to be contained in the _Layout.cshtml file so that they are global and work correctly across the entire page. My JavaScript scripts are intended to trigger interactions, such as <div class="swiper-button-next">.
I have already searched through threads related to similar issues, including this one on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue and could help me? Maybe someone knows the solution to correctly load blazor.server.js in _Layout.cshtml so that my JavaScript scripts work properly across the entire page?

Hi satck, I don't quite understand your description. Do you mean that when you navigate to page1.razor through the page click, you don't see the js code running? If so, please stay on the page1.razor page and refresh the browser to run it again to see if the js code works properly.

If it is as described above, you need to understand the operating mechanism of Blazor Server. When it is loaded for the first time, all the js codes in the layout will be loaded. When you click on the page to jump to other pages, the components will be refreshed through websocket. Only by refreshing the page, such as HTTP request, will the js file code in the layout be loaded and run again.

If not, please create a brand new project that reproduces the issue, add detailed test steps, and I'd be happy to help you investigate. And please hide your sensitive inforamtion, it can keep your data safely.

Try this.

Load blazor and DOM first and set booleans after they've each loaded.
Run your your script programmatically once you have confirmation they have each loaded.

(Also, did you mean to for those stylesheets to be CSS? I corrected that below.)
Like this:
<!-- _Layout.cshtml -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/picture.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Pager.css">
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
        const scripts = [
            'js/test/custom.js',
            'js/test/swiper.js',
            'js/test/gallery.js',
            'js/test/Pager.js',
            'js/test/picture.js',
            'js/main.js'
        ];

        let domReady = false;
        let blazorReady = false;

        // Check if both conditions are met before loading
        function checkAndLoadScripts() {
            if (domReady && blazorReady) {
                scripts.forEach(src => {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = src;
                    script.async = false;
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                });
            }
        }

        // Set flags and check conditions when each event fires
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            domReady = true;
            checkAndLoadScripts();
        });

        window.addEventListener('blazor:start', () => {
            blazorReady = true;
            checkAndLoadScripts();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Hope that helps.

Unfortunately, it’s not working. When I use your code, the scripts are not visible in the developer tools -> network. However, I modified your code to:

<!-- _Layout.cshtml -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/picture.js">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Pager.js">


    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <!-- Load Blazor first -->
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <!-- Wait for Blazor, then load your scripts -->
   
<script> 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        loadScripts([
            'js/test/custom.js',
            'js/test/swiper.js',
            'js/test/gallery.js',
            'js/test/Pager.js',
            'js/test/picture.js',
            'js/main.js'
        ]);
    });

    function loadScripts(srcs) {
        srcs.forEach(src => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


Now the scripts are visible in the developer tools -> network, but they still don’t work. The issue remains the same: when I have <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> in the _Layout.cshtml file, my scripts stop working.

I modified my answer to include DOM loading.
